# Can't register given path of type 'SOURCE' because it's out of content root. - CORDA TEMPLATE JAVA

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am working with CORDA new template Java to build a Peer-to-peer app. I tried to build the template, while importing, struck with the following error:

> Can't register given path of type 'SOURCE' because it's out of content
>   root. Content root: 'C:/Users/jayapolvst/CordaP2P-lendingApp/clients'
>   Given path: 'C:\Users\jayapolvst\CordaP2P-lendingApp\config\dev'

Tried with different networks to speed up the importing process.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a path problem, I'm not sure how you downloaded the sample but try cloning a sample project or cordapp locally (I recommend this one https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Basic/yo-cordapp) and then using IntelliJ to open the project. (remember to OPEN the project, do NOT use IntelliJ to import as that will blow away project settings).

As long as you have the project settings configured correctly, (java 1.8 in project structure) hopefully you won't continue to have issues.

Feel free to comment here if you do and I can try to help.